# Powershell 2.0 - loop through records in CSV for FTP Login validate and update csv with confirmation

Tags: csv, import, null, powershell-2.0, counter

### Current issue, probably stupid simple but have been grinding my wheels for awhile. I have 600+ FTP accounts to validate if they are able to be logged on. Verified field to be updated in CSV.

CSV Sample:
Connection,Name,Path,Password,Phonetic,Client Name,Client ID,Verified
FTP,**BFG**ftp,d:\data\ftpaccounts\BFGftp,8Wu8Agec8$,(Eight - WHISKEY - uniform - Eight - ALPHA - golf - echo - charlie - Eight - Dollar),(Nine - papa - ECHO - foxtrot - ROMEO - Two - kilo - echo - NOVEMBER - Two),,

### FTP,bookitftp,d:\data\ftpaccounts\flipitftp,i3439flip12@@,,Flipitftp,30342,

Missing statement block after 'else' keyword.
At C:\Users\mgoeres\Desktop\B-SWIFT FTP TEST2.ps1:118 char:10
+               else  <<<< ($i++){ $GetFTP }
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingStatementBlockAfterElse

---

FTP ACCOUNT VALIDATOR

```
   Function Get-FtpDirectory($Directory) {
    #Example
    #$Server = "ftp://ftp.example.com/"
    #$User = "anonymous@example.com"
    #$Pass = "anonymous@anonymous.com"

    $Server = "ftp://ftp.localhost.com/"
    $User = $FTPLogon
    $Pass = $FTPPass


# Credentials
    $FTPRequest = [System.Net.FtpWebRequest]::Create("$($Server)$($Directory)")
    $FTPRequest.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($User,$Pass)
    $FTPRequest.Method = [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+FTP]::ListDirectoryDetails

    # Don't want Binary, Keep Alive unecessary.
    $FTPRequest.UseBinary = $False
    $FTPRequest.KeepAlive = $False

    $FTPResponse = $FTPRequest.GetResponse()

    $ResponseStream = $FTPResponse.GetResponseStream()

    # Create a nice Array of the detailed directory listing
    $StreamReader = New-Object System.IO.Streamreader $ResponseStream
    $DirListing = (($StreamReader.ReadToEnd()) -split [Environment]::NewLine)
    $StreamReader.Close()

    # Remove first two elements ( . and .. ) and last element (\n)
    $DirListing = $DirListing[2..($DirListing.Length-2)] 

    # Close the FTP connection so only one is open at a time
    $FTPResponse.Close()

    # This array will hold the final result
    $FileTree = @()

    # Loop through the listings
    foreach ($CurLine in $DirListing) {

        # Split line into space separated array
        $LineTok = ($CurLine -split '\ +')

        # Get the filename (can even contain spaces)
        $CurFile = $LineTok[8..($LineTok.Length-1)]

        # Figure out if it's a directory. Super hax.
        $DirBool = $LineTok[0].StartsWith("d")

        # Determine what to do next (file or dir?)
        If ($DirBool) {
            # Recursively traverse sub-directories
            $FileTree += ,(Get-FtpDirectory "$($Directory)$($CurFile)/")
            }    

            Else {
            # Add the output to the file tree
            $FileTree += ,"$($Directory)$($CurFile)"
             }

    }
                if (!$FileTree -eq $null) { 
                $Verified = "Y" 
                Return $FileTree
                                      }
                    else {
                    $Verified = "Failed"}


}



# Update data record field "Verified" in CSV '$data' file with status value[Y,Failed,Other]
```

#### There is where the import of the FTP login ID and Password should start

```
#Column Names [Connection,Name,Path,Password,Phonetic,Client Name,Client ID,Verified]

#Variables
$AllName = @()
$AllPassword = @()
$AllVerified = @()
$data = @()
$FTPLogon = @()
$FTPPass = @()
$response = @()
$GetFTP = Get-FtpDirectory

# Import CSV File "FTP_Account_List_with_Password_and_Path.csv"
$data = Import-Csv C:\Users\mgoeres\Desktop\FTP_Account_List_with_Password_and_Path.csv | where-object {$_.Connection -eq "FTP"} 

# This import allows key columns to be referenced as variables.
#Import-Csv C:\Users\mgoeres\Desktop\FTP_Account_List_with_Password_and_Path.csv | ForEach-Object {
#$AllName += $_.Name
#$AllPassword += $_.Password
#$AllVerified += $_.Verified}
```

```
# Simple test to see if CSV was imported into '$data' and column headers are working as variables
$data|select-object Name,Connection,Verified
Write-Host "CSV File Opened and Loaded"
```

```
## Select (next)record from '$data' and store correlating values in '$UserName' and '$Password'
# .EXAMPLE '$data[0].Password' <= First records Password value.     
# .EXAMPLE '$data[1].Name' <= Second records Name value. 

for ($i=0; $i -lt $data.count; $i++){
    $FTPLogon = $data[$i].Name
    $FTPPass = $data[$i].Password
    $Verified = $data[$i].Verified }
        if ($Verifed -eq $null){ $GetFTP }
            else ($i++){ $GetFTP }
```

Comment: The last if..else statement, never seen anyone try and parameterize it before. I don't think you can do that. Do the $i++ inside the else{}

Comment: for ($i=0; $i -lt $data.count; $i++){
  $FTPLogon = $data[$i].Name
  $FTPPass = $data[$i].Password
  $Verified = $data[$i].Verified }
   if ($Verifed -eq $null){ $GetFTP }
    else {$i++, $GetFTP }

Comment: Is this what you had in mind?  It still seems like it its not getting to the function call and for some reason the counter $i is equal to the total record count? is it counting through to the last record or is it getting it from $data.count somehow?

Comment: Remove the dollar sign from the $GetFTP

Comment: $GetFTP is a variable:  $GetFTP = Get-FtpDirectory